# How to add pagination to this dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table with its respective data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Columns]
(
    [ColumnId] INT,
    [TableId] INT NOT NULL,
    [ColumnName] NVARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    [Order] INT,
    [Key] BIT
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tables]
(
    [TableId] INT,
    [TableName] NVARCHAR(200),
    [DistrictId] INT
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RowValues]
(
    [ColumnId] INT NOT NULL,
    [RowNumber] INT NOT NULL,
    [Value] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)


insert into [Columns] values (1, 1, 'StudentName', 1, 1)
insert into [Columns] values (2, 1, 'Grade', 1, 0)
insert into [Columns] values (3, 1, 'Year', 1, 0)
insert into [Columns] values (4, 1, 'Section', 1, 0)

insert into [Columns] values (5, 2, 'TeacherName', 1, 1)
insert into [Columns] values (6, 2, 'Department', 1, 0)

insert into [Tables] values (1, 'Student', 1)
insert into [Tables] values (2, 'Teacher', 1)

insert into [RowValues] values (1, 1, 'Student Alan')
insert into [RowValues] values (2, 1, '99')
insert into [RowValues] values (3, 1, '1st')
insert into [RowValues] values (4, 1, 'Section 1')

insert into [RowValues] values (1, 2, 'Student Alex')
insert into [RowValues] values (2, 2, '98')
insert into [RowValues] values (3, 2, '1st')
insert into [RowValues] values (4, 2, 'Section 1')

insert into [RowValues] values (1, 3, 'Student Alfonso')
insert into [RowValues] values (2, 3, '97')
insert into [RowValues] values (3, 3, '1st')
insert into [RowValues] values (4, 3, 'Section 1')

insert into [RowValues] values (1, 4, 'Student Ben')
insert into [RowValues] values (2, 4, '96')
insert into [RowValues] values (3, 4, '1st')
insert into [RowValues] values (4, 4, 'Section 1')

insert into [RowValues] values (1, 5, 'Student Cathy')
insert into [RowValues] values (2, 5, '95')
insert into [RowValues] values (3, 5, '1st')
insert into [RowValues] values (4, 5, 'Section 1')

insert into [RowValues] values (5, 1, 'Teacher Tesso')
insert into [RowValues] values (6, 1, 'Biology Dept')

insert into [RowValues] values (5, 2, 'Teacher Marvin')
insert into [RowValues] values (6, 2, 'Math Dept')
```

I wanted to be able to sort the dynamic column
example sort by 'StudentName' ASC it would sort data using column returning

When sorting by `StudentName`:

```
StudentName         Grade       Year        Section
'Student Alan'      99          '1st'       'Section 1'
'Student Alex'      98          '1st'       'Section 1'
'Student Alfonso'   97          '1st'       'Section 1'
.
.
.
```

When sorting by `Grade ASC`:

```
StudentName         Grade       Year        Section
'Student Cathy'     95          '1st'       'Section 1'
'Student Ben'       96          '1st'       'Section 1'
'Student Alfonso'   97          '1st'       'Section 1'
.
.
.
```

When sorting by `TeacherName ASC` (different table)

```
TeacherName         Department
'Teacher Marvin'    'Math Dept'
'Teacher Tesso'     'Biology Dept'
.
.
.
```

I have manage to accomplish this.

The problem is adding Pagination to my dynamic SQL string.

This is my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_DynamicSearch_Paged]
    (@districtId INT,
     @searchTerm NVARCHAR(max),
     @pageNumber INT = 1,
     @pageSize INT = 10,
     @sortColumn NVARCHAR(20),
     @sortDirection INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max),
            @sql nvarchar(max),
            @rows int

    SET @rows = (@pageNumber - 1) * @pageSize;

    SELECT 
        @columns = (SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName)
                    FROM Tables AS T
                    INNER JOIN Columns AS C ON T.TableId = C.TableId
                    WHERE T.districtId = @districtId
                    ORDER BY C.[Order]
                    FOR XML PATH(''))

    SELECT 
        @columns = (SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName)
                    FROM Tables AS T
                    INNER JOIN Columns AS C ON T.TableId = C.TableId
                    WHERE T.districtId = @districtId
                    ORDER BY C.[Order]
                    FOR XML PATH(''))

    SELECT [Columns] = REPLACE(REPLACE(value,'[',''),']','') 
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(STUFF(@Columns, 1, 1, ''),',')

    SET @sql = N'
    SELECT * INTO #Fields FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnName ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN,
        districtId,
        ColumnName
        , V.[Value]
    FROM Tables AS T
    INNER JOIN Columns AS C
        ON T.TableId = C.TableId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RowValues AS V
        ON C.ColumnId = V.ColumnId
    ) t
    PIVOT (
        MIN([Value])
        FOR [ColumnName]
        IN ('
            + STUFF(@Columns, 1, 1, '') +
        ')
    ) AS PivotTable
    
    DECLARE @KeyColumnName NVARCHAR(100)
    SELECT @KeyColumnName = ColumnName
    FROM Tables AS T
    INNER JOIN Columns AS C
        ON T.TableId = C.TableId
    WHERE T.districtId = ' + CAST(@districtId AS VARCHAR) + '
        AND C.IsKey = 1

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = ''
    SELECT *
    FROM #Fields
    WHERE '' + @KeyColumnName + '' LIKE '''''+ @searchTerm +'%''''
    ''
    OFFSET ('+CAST(@rows AS VARCHAR)+') ROWS
    FETCH NEXT ' +CAST(@pageSize AS VARCHAR) +' ROWS ONLY;
    EXEC sp_EXECUTESQL @sql
    '

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END
```

I just added the

```
    OFFSET ('+CAST(@rows AS VARCHAR)+') ROWS
    FETCH NEXT ' +CAST(@pageSize AS VARCHAR) +' ROWS ONLY;
    EXEC sp_EXECUTESQL @sql
```

and now it doesn't work

Comment: There is no Columns.IsKey column in your test data, but there is condition AND C.IsKey = 1 in your procedure. Just a tip to review your test data or procedure code. It would be helpful for the one who would run your code.

Comment: I recommend to provide testing call of your procedure for others.

Comment: Could you be a bit more vague about "now it doesn't work"? Did the fire damage preclude rebooting the system? Was there an error message? Did `EXEC` never return? Aside: Best practice is to _always_ specify a length for variable length data types, e.g. `VarChar`. The default length is sometimes `1`, other times `30`.

Comment: Why are you injecting your parameters instead of parametrising them? Why are you not properly quoting your dynamic object names? This code is **dangerous**. I can't stress enough (like I did in your other question), with respect, you clearly don't understand how to properly, and *safely* use dynamic SAL so why are you using a design that mandates it. Right now you have insecure code that is just waiting to be exploited.

Comment: You have a number of side issues with your code: To avoid XML entitization in `FOR XML` you should use this `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')`. It's unclear why the dynamic SQL is *itself* executing dynamic SQL, it seems you can construct the whole thing together, and thereby avoid passing through parameters. If you cannot, then at least pass through parameters properly, rather than injecting them. `@sortColumn` should be declared as `sysname`. Unclear why you need to insert into a temp table and could not just select from the first query using a subquery instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OFFSET and FETCH clauses are the options of the ORDER BY clause. They allow you to limit the number of rows to be returned by a query.
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch/
I think you need to declare ORDER BY